# How to fix: CS1061 error. How would I create properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a project and I am getting this CS1061 error. It says, "'ErrorViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ShowRequestID' and no accessible extension method "ShowRequestID' accepting a first argument of type 'ErrorViewModel' could be found". I am getting the same thing for 'RequestID'.

Would I need to to declare 'ShowRequestID' and 'RequestId' in my 'ErrorViewModel' file? I am having trouble with the properties.

Below is where my errors are:

```
@model ErrorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

@if (Model.ShowRequestID)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
</p>
```

below is my 'ErrorViewModel'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ArtistCollection.Models
{
    public class ErrorViewModel
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: the model is empty.

Comment: what exactly would i need to add into the model?

Comment: You need to add a property for every single piece of information you want that model to contain. At a minimum, that's ShowRequestID and RequestId since your view is trying to access those properties on your model. If you don't know what a property is or how to create it, then of course you should check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), just like with any other concept that isn't familiar to you.